# Encountering Class Not Found Exception Error After Upgrading Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

I have a question that needs help. In my program, I used to use jetty-util-6.1.26.jar, but due to security vulnerabilities, I recently upgraded it to jetty-util-9.4.53.v20231009.jar. After upgrading, I am getting a "class not found" exception when trying to start the project in IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: File Explorer - jetty-util-6.1.26.jar]

[image: NoClassDefFoundError from Spring / Alibaba]

[image: File Explorer - jetty-util-9.4.53.v20231009.jar]

I replaced the `jetty-util.jar` package.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Jetty 6 was declared End of Life back in 2010, and should not be in use after that.

In the years since you started your project, both Dubbo and Jetty have been donated to various open source foundations.

- Jetty went to Eclipse in 2009 - https://eclipse.dev/jetty/
- Dubbo went to Apache in 2017 - https://dubbo.apache.org/

In both cases, the package namespace changed to conform to the open source foundation rules.

- Dubbo went from `com.alibaba.dubbo.*` to [`org.apache.dubbo.*`](https://github.com/apache/dubbo/blob/3.2/dubbo-remoting/dubbo-remoting-http/src/main/java/org/apache/dubbo/remoting/http/jetty/JettyHttpServer.java)
- Jetty went from `org.mortbay.jetty.*` to [`org.eclipse.jetty.*`](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPool.java)

In short, you'll need to upgrade both.